# jquery/javascript alert popup on a set time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, timeout, alert

Do you know if there exists any Jquery plugin that displays an alert popup message every period of time, or one in a set period of time? For instance: your time expires in x minutes, the timeout being given.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why plugin when there is a native [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) javascript function?

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // this will execute every 5 minutes => show the alert here
}, 300000);
```

Of course you could use a [plugin to do sexier notifications](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/bounce-in-box-plugin-jquery/) rather than a boring alert.

Comment: the plugin doing the sexier notification is onclick. can i make it show up on my interval? thanks!

Comment: @dana, `$('#box').bounceBoxToggle();` triggers the box and `$('#box').bounceBoxHide();` hides it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [jQuery.Timeout](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-timeout), it should do what you need!

```
$.timeout(5000).done(function() { 
    alert("5 seconds later..."); 
});
```